# plot in matlab with similar xlabels spaces

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a figure in matlab, where xlabel is 2 power n values, where n is an integer and ylable includes any vector values,  I need to plot those values and keep x vector to be equal spaced. What I do now is correct but small spaces in xlabel are shown when x values are small while that becomes larger with higher values of x values.

That is what I did:

```
M = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256];
s1 = [104   136   168   200   232   264   296   328]; 

figure(1) 
semilogy(M, s1, 'ko-', 'LineWidth', 1); hold on;   %


grid; 
axis ([0 256 0 600])
xticks(M);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to have evenly spaced xticks is to use a linear vector `(0,1,2,3,etc...)` the same length as your data. You plot your `y` data versus this `xa` (*X Apparent*) vector, then just modify the `xticklabels` to display the proper power of 2 corresponding to each point.

So for your code:

```
max_xa = numel(M)-1 ; % number of "x" points (-1 because we'll start at 0)
xa = 0:max_xa ;       % generate the x-apparent vector

figure
% Plot your "sl" values versus "xa"
semilogy(xa, s1, 'ko-', 'LineWidth', 1); grid on ; 
axis ([0 max_xa 0 600]) % adust limits
xticklabels(M);         % adjust X tick labels
```

will generate the following figure:
[image: even X ticks]

Note: We started the X apparent vector at `0` instead of `1` because otherwise Matlab would automatically insert a xtick at the value `0` and our `xticklabels` would all be offset by one position.

Answer (score 0):

Your issues will remain unless you drop some xticklabels or better use loglog to plot which retains the feature of parabolic data.

Use following lines in your code:
loglog(M, s1, 'ko-', 'LineWidth', 1); hold on;   %

You will get this result [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiTO0.jpg)